# Any better way to internationalize Metadata with next-intl in a Next.js 13+ page?

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13, next.js14, next-intl

I would like to internationalize text on every page in my app, as well as the title of the pages.

Starting with the text, as per the [next-intl documentation page on internationalizing components](https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/environments/server-client-components#shared-components), it can be done like this:

```js
import {useTranslations} from 'next-intl';
 
export default function UserDetails({user}) {
  const t = useTranslations('UserProfile');
 
  return (
    <section>
      <h2>{t('heading')}</h2>
    </section>
  );
}
```

As for the metadata, as per the [relevant page from the documentation](https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/environments/metadata-route-handlers#metadata-api), it is done like this:

```js
import {getTranslations} from 'next-intl/server';
 
export async function generateMetadata({params: {locale}}) {
  const t = await getTranslations({locale, namespace: 'Metadata'});
 
  return {
    title: t('title')
  };
}
```

So, overall, for each page, the boilerplate will look like this:

```js
import {useTranslations} from 'next-intl';
import {getTranslations} from 'next-intl/server';

export async function generateMetadata({params: {locale}}) {
  const t = await getTranslations({locale, namespace: 'Metadata'});

  return {
    title: t('title')
  };
}

export default function UserDetails({user}) {
  const t = useTranslations('UserProfile');

  return (
    <section>
      <h2>{t('heading')}</h2>
    </section>
  );
}
```

**Is there a way to achieve this without declaring `t` twice on every page?**